# Divergence theorem with nonorientable surfaces

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

The general theorem from which Gauss’s law stems, divergence theorem, states that

> the volume integral of the divergence $\nabla\cdot\bf F$ of $\bf F$ over $V$ and the surface integral of $\bf F$ over the boundary $\partial V$ of $V$ are related by $$\int_V \left( \nabla\cdot\bf F\right) \, dV = \int_{\partial V} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \bf{a}$$ [*Wolfram MathWorld*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergenceTheorem.html)

In class, we would write the righthand side of this equation as $$\iint\limits_{\mathrm{closed}} \vec F \cdot \hat n \, dA$$ where (as you might have guessed) $\hat n$ was a unit vector that was normal to the surface at each point. (Actually, we would draw an oval overtop of the double integral sign to show it was closed, but MathJax doesn’t support that.)

Of course, there exist closed surfaces for which $\hat n$ cannot be systematically defined, called [*nonorientable surfaces*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonorientableSurface.html).

My question is: **How could divergence theorem be applied to nonorientable surfaces?** Of course, an obvious solution is to not choose a nonorientable surface over which to evaluate the integral, but that’s not what I’m aiming for.

*(If this question is more appropriate for physics SE, please mention so in the comments.)*

Comment: Are you sure there is a closed non orientable surface in 3 dimensional real space?

Comment: @Paul The Klein bottle, for one.

Comment: The Klein bottle is not in naturally in 3 d space.

Comment: @Paul How do you mean? Are you not free to select whichever Gaussian surface is best suited to evaluate the integral?

Comment: I am saying your surface has to actually be in 3d space.

Comment: @Paul I found a picture of a glass one online… Does that count?

Comment: @Paul No need to restrict to 3 dimensions since this is the divergence theorem. There's a perfectly reasonable realisation of the Klein bottle in 4D.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124484/stokes-theorem-for-manifolds-without-orientation (but the right thing to use is differential forms, not vector fields).

Comment: Even a Klein bottle resting nicely in $\Bbb R^4$ has no "inside" or "outside", since a 2-surface cannot separate $\Bbb R^4$.  We recall the old ***rhyme doggerel:***  Three jolly sailors from Blaydon on Tyne/Went to sea in a bottle by Klein;/Since the sea was entirely inside the hull/The scenery seen was exceedingly dull.

Comment: @user56478 you found a picture of an immersed image of a klein bottle that is not embedded, that is, it has self intersections. the abstract klein bottle doesn't have self intersections... you cant put it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without turning it into something else